# INSERT while LOOPing

Tags: postgresql, loops, plpgsql, sql-insert

i'd like to insert some records into a table while looping. Records are passed as a varchar tab to a function ie.:

```
create function a(tab varchar[]) RETURNS void AS
$$
DECLARE 
  b varchar(20);
BEGIN
  FOREACH b IN ARRAY tab
   LOOP
      INSERT INTO....;
   END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

However, when executing there is the error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FOREACH"
LINE 1: FOREACH  $1  IN ARRAY tab LOOP INSERT INTO x (c, ...
QUERY:  FOREACH  $1  IN ARRAY tab LOOP INSERT INTO x (c) VALUES ( $1)
CONTEXT:  SQL statement in PL/PgSQL function " near line ...

********** ERROR **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "FOREACH"
```

Does anybody know why and how to fix this?

Comment: Which version of Postgres? `FOREACH IN ARRAY` seems to have been added in 9.1.

Comment: **Always** provide the version number you are working with. This is a programmers' site, you should *know* to do that. Also, if you provide a complete example, chances are, you don't need to loop at all and it will be much faster that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`FOREACH`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-FOREACH-ARRAY) construct was added in 9.1. For earlier versions you can use [`unnest()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) function the following way:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION a(tab varchar[]) RETURNS void AS
$$
DECLARE 
  b varchar(20);
BEGIN
  FOR b IN SELECT unnest(tab)
  LOOP
    INSERT INTO x(c) VALUES (b);
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 3):

Since PostgreSQL 9.1 there is also a [built-in way to loop through array slices](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-FOREACH-ARRAY):

```
FOREACH x SLICE 1 IN ARRAY $1
LOOP
   RAISE NOTICE 'row = %', x;
END LOOP;
```

Where `x` must be a matching *array* type and ...

> The SLICE value must be an integer constant not larger than the number of dimensions of the array

For 1-dimensional arrays just omit the `SLICE` part and `x` can be a simple type like you display in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add one thing, and that is that unnest unnests all levels of an array:

```
select * from unnest(ARRAY[ARRAY[1,2,3],Array[5,6,7]]);
 unnest 
--------
      1
      2
      3
      5
      6
      7
(6 rows)
```

If you want to loop through one level of a multi-dimensional array, you should loop through the following instead

```
    FOR out_count IN
                    array_lower(in_transactions, 1) ..
                    array_upper(in_transactions, 1)
    LOOP
        -- Fill the bulk payments table
        INSERT INTO bulk_payments_in(id, amount)
        VALUES (in_transactions[out_count][1],
                in_transactions[out_count][2]);
    END LOOP;
```

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.1+ has a dedicated feature for this.